# Use of dynamic AND in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
DECLARE
   dynaCol  varchar2(200);
   varCol varchar2(100);

BEGIN

   dbms_output.put_line(dynaCol);
   select name into varCol from  GSSP_ETL.DEMO_TABLE_CHECK where ID='1'|| (SELECT q'$ and optional='N'$' NAME FROM DUAL) ;
   dbms_output.put_line(varCol);

END;
```

Though I have a row for `id=1` and `optional=N` I still get no data found error.

`SELECT q'$ and optional='N'$' NAME FROM DUAL` gives me `and optional='N'`, so there is nothing wrong to use like this.

Please help if anyone know the reason or better way to append the and in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your original query is looking for the row with ID = "1 and optional = 'N'" which causes the problem.

You should use dynamic SQL if you want to have variable WHERE clause:

```
SQL> create table t (id, name, optional)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 'XXX','N' from dual
  4  /

SQL> select * from t;

        ID NAM O                                                                
---------- --- -                                                                
         1 XXX N                                                                


SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2   dynaCol  varchar2(200) := q'[ and optional='N']';
  3   varCol varchar2(100);
  4   p_id int := 1;
  5  begin
  6  
  7    execute immediate
  8    ' select name from t where id = :x '||dynaCol
  9    into varCol using p_id;
 10    dbms_output.put_line(varCol);
 11  end;
 12  /
XXX
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry thans for reply but all my columns are varchar. so putting them in quotes.

Comment: Can we avoid execute immediate and do it.

Comment: In PL/SQL - no, you can't. If you call SQL from C++/Java, you can compose your SQL like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i couldn't comment due to my low reputation..

No,its not possible to do with out immediate i think so,the best way is what Dmitry did.
Its possible to send whole select statement dynamically but a part with out execute immediate..

Comment: But Madara i dont ve the luxury of using a pl sql  inside my jboss switchyard framework.. I can only use sql query statemets. So can i append somethng like this : execute immediate 'select count(name) from GSSP_ETL.DEMO_TABLE_CHECK where id=1'|| q'[ and  optional='N']'

Comment: YEA COULD UNDERSTAND BUT I THINK ITS NOT POSSIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

...You got close.

Since you're using PL/SQL, why not consider creating a persistent object such as a `PL/SQL Stored Procedure` instead?  There will be less code on the JBOSS side and the database schema layout will be further separated from the code you intended on accessing the database.

**The Demonstration Table**

This is an interpretation from pieces of your original post.  This is the table I used to test out my recommendations.

```
 CREATE TABLE  "DEMO_TABLE_CHECK" 
    (     "ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
      "NAME" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
      "OPTIONAL" VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
      CONSTRAINT "DEMO_TABLE_CHECK_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
    )
 /
```

*My test data*:

[image: Sample Data from DEMO_TABLE_CHECK]

**The Procedure Source Code**

```
 CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_example(p_id IN number, 
    p_opt IN varchar2 default null) 
 IS
    Result varchar2(100);

 BEGIN
    SELECT name
      INTO Result
      FROM GSSP_ETL.DEMO_TABLE_CHECK
     WHERE id = p_id
       AND optional = nvl(p_opt, optional); 
    
 dbms_output.put_line(Result);

 END proc_example;
```

> Notice that this example solution actually does away with the dynamic SQL calls proposed in previous solutions.  The realm of PL/SQL procedural code is likely to accommodate for pushing around and concatenating strings of SQL commands.

**An Example Call and the Output**

```
 begin
 proc_example(p_id=> 1, p_opt=>'N');

 end;


 -- output:

 ALPHA



 begin
 proc_example(p_id=> 1, p_opt=> null);
 proc_example(p_id=> 1);

 end;

 -- output:

 ALPHA
 ALPHA
```

All this PL/SQL code, which was originally in an a block passed from the part of your program that accessed the database will now reside on the database.

### Discussion of the PL/SQL Procedure Design

The optional part of the query, represented by `p_opt`, has a default designation.  This means if there is no value for that parameter, then the procedure will ignore it and assume it is equal to the defined default value.  No errors will be thrown.

```
 AND optional = nvl(p_opt, optional)
```

This line is a replacement for the add-on SQL string.  the input parameter `p_opt`, whether it was supplied (such as = 'N') or skipped ( implied to = null ), the SQL script includes or excludes the effect of this operator based on the "switching" parameter supplied.

**Closing Comments:**

> If you want to see a better differentiation of results based on that last, dynamic SQL command, you might want to try scenarios where the first criteria is actually ambiguous, such as multiple instances if the `ID` column. (If ID = 1 was true for more than one record...)   But of that set of results, have the second criteria identify something unique when in combination with the first.